# Cypress - How can I disable retries on cy.request?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I have a test which:

Does an initial GET:

```
 cy.request(setHeaders('GET', `${url}?params..`, undefined)).then(
        (response) => {
            // log past 10 results + length
```

Followed by a single POST:

```
cy.request(setHeaders('POST', ${url}, trafficAnalyticMessage)).then((postResponse) => {
// ...
```

And finally, another GET

```
cy.request(setHeaders('GET', `${url}?params..`, undefined)).then(
                (response) => {
                    // log past 10 results + length
```

So, when I run sequence of events manually on something like Postman, I can visually see that it behaves as I expect, i.e. a new record is added, and the latest record is new (i.e. wasn't seen on the first GET)

But when I run this on Cypress, using that code, I'm seeing that the logging from the final GET shows that 3-5 new records have been added!

I've tried looking into this, and have come across the idea that it could be some kind of "retryability". Is there a way to disable this, for requests? Specifically for the ones in this test alone?

Answer (score 0):

There's a different way to set the headers in a Cypress request, but I think you just need

```js
cy.request(`${url}?params..`)    // GET is the default
  .then(response => {
    ...
  })
```

You may be seeing retries due to network errors, since by default `retryOnNetworkFailure` is `true`.

You can turn it off in the options

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: `${url}?params..`,
  retryOnNetworkFailure: false
})   
.then(response => {
  ...
})
```

---

An example with headers is here [examples/server-communication__request](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/65cef746458f12dae141e72a75c9f47118ef512b/examples/server-communication__request/cypress/integration/spec.js#L29)

```js
  it('sends additional cookies via cy.request headers', () => {
    // https://on.cypress.io/request
    // can add more headers and cookies
    cy.request({
      url: '/print-cookies',
      headers: {
        'Cookie': 'cookieA=valueA; cookieB=valueB',
      },
    })
    .its('body')
    // the cookies sent to the server are the combination
    // of the cookies set by the page via cy.visit
    // and the cookies we sent via the Cookie header
    .should('deep.equal', {
      mycookie: 'testcookie',
      cookieA: 'valueA',
      cookieB: 'valueB',
    })
  })
```

Comment: do you reckon the "retry" functionality would be responsible for this kind of behaviour? like surely if it retried and failed, it wouldn't actually post it... i.e. retry until success should mean ONLY one successful POST occurs.. not 4

Comment: No I don't. Without setting up a test system to actually measure, I guess the problem is caused by use of `setHeaders()` inside the `cy.request()`.